# Azure PowerShell Runbook

Tags: runbook

I am new to *Azure Power* shell run book. I wrote example *hello world* program. According to documentation it should show output. But it did not show output. I have tested it in test-pane. It show status "completed: but it does not output the string. Below is the code:

```
Workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
{
    Write-Output "hello world"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally It should work. It should show output under completed as shown in image attached.[image]